# Disable smooth scrolling in WordPad?

Tags: windows-10, scrolling, mouse-wheel, wordpad

Is there any way to turn off Smooth Scrolling in WordPad in Windows 10, v1903?

When I use the mouse-wheel, I want one "click" of the wheel to result in a single change of screen state. Any kind of interpolated "smooth" scrolling induces motion sickness for me, especially when it isn't actually smooth as with WordPad.

Such issues seem to be common [[1]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-smooth-scrolling/09965494-7aa7-4e85-b282-6b5bd352bd0c?page=1).

For Browsers, it can typically be enabled with a browser-setting. For Microsoft Office 365, enabling *“Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible)”* in *“Control Panel → Ease of Access Center → Make the computer easier to see”* does the trick [[2]](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2edca14d-a7b0-4f55-90f1-17b760965513/how-to-disable-smooth-scroll-from-most-recent-word-update?forum=Office2016setupdeploy).

Sadly that setting doesn't affect the modernized Settings interface, nor does it affect WordPad.

---

<sup>[1] https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-smooth-scrolling/09965494-7aa7-4e85-b282-6b5bd352bd0c?page=1

[2] https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2edca14d-a7b0-4f55-90f1-17b760965513/how-to-disable-smooth-scroll-from-most-recent-word-update?forum=Office2016setupdeploy</sup>

Comment: Control Panel > Mouse > Wheels tab. Change to 1.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I don't have the value as `1`, but I also don't have smooth scrolling. Interesting.

Comment: Might be an attribute of the mouse driver, since I can't find any setting for it.

Comment: @DavidPostill That doesn't disable smooth scrolling. It just hides the effect by making scrolling so painfully slow, that the difference is harder to tell.